# The declared package "" does not match the expected package

Tags: java, class, visual-studio-code

I'm able to compile and run my code but there is always an error showing in VSCode. Earlier there was a pop up I don't remember what and I clicked "apply globally" and it's been this way since.

Output is there but so is the error
[image]

The declared package "" does not match the expected package
[image]

Comment: How did you compile the second example?

Comment: Something is wrong with your source directory setup. It seems that the file is in a folder "Java" under the source root, so it wants the package name to be "Java". You probably want "Java" itself to be the root. Check the build settings for the source code location.

Comment: plz Take a look at this : https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/274

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to the [comment of @beatrice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718171/the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package/67651796#comment96222237_54718171) above, I found the answer [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/274#issuecomment-829534246).

My `.vscode\settings.json` file had some paths explicitly added. I had added them manually when Visual Studio code was not misbehaving, by right-clicking on certain project folders and doing "add Folder to Java source path".

The solution for me was to basically remove all of them from `.vscode\settings.json`, replacing its contents with:

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [""]
}
```

This finally made VsCode work again.