# The declared package does not match expected package

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*; //The declared package "" does not match the expected package "jdbc" 

class Oraclecon {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            //step1 load the driver class  

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //step2 create  the connection object  

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(

                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "system");

            //step3 create the statement object  

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            //step4 execute query  

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from JNTURESULTS");

            while (rs.next())

                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  " + rs.getString(3));

            //step5 close the connection object  

            con.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: getting compilation error at the first line

Comment: Add the package name at the top in your java class.
As the error suggests it should be package jdbc;

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718171/the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code doesn't declare a package (it is in the default, nameless package).

Your file structure is probably something like

```
src
  \-jdbc
      \-Oraclecon.java
```

When you compile with `src` as the root, then Java expects your `Oraclecon.java` to declare its package as `jdbc`. To fix this, add `package jdbc;` at the top of `Oraclecon.java`.

Be aware that a package name like `jdbc` does not match the [Java naming conventions for packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).